# MVC 3 - change field value prior to validation

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, validation

I have a model with a field

```
    [Required(ErrorMessage = "Email Address is required")]
    [RegularExpression(@"^[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4}$", ErrorMessage = "Not a valid email address.")]
    [Display(Name = "Email Address")]
    public virtual string EmailAddress { get; set; }
```

And the validation fails if i have an empty space at the beginning of the email. I would like to write a JQuery method to trim the field before it is validated.
I tried with a blur attached but the blur is executed after validation. 
How can i solve this?

Thanks.

Comment: data annotations fires when the form submits not on blur.

Comment: @KartikeyaKhosla data annotations also fires on blur once form submitted.

Comment: Don't you want to trim in just onChange this field?

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to fix it would be to change the regex to allow spaces before and after the email:

```
"^ *[a-zA-Z0-9._%+-]+@[a-zA-Z0-9.-]+\.[a-zA-Z]{2,4} *$"
```

You can then trim the field on the server side before saving it.

I would recommend the use of [EmailAddressAttribute](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.dataannotations.emailaddressattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) instead of **RegularExpression** though.
On the client side you can remove the spaces like this:
[jquery validate - replace commas in field before validation occurs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15415814/jquery-validate-replace-commas-in-field-before-validation-occurs)